# Display pdf byte from database in div in ASP.Net Webforms

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, webforms, byte

I have a problem with displaying a pdf in a div from my database. My pdf file is written in bytes and I get that value, but when I run my project nothing is displayed. Even though if I put that value in a Image as ImageUrl, I get the value but nothing is shown. So if anyone has an idea how can I display my pdf from the database, I would be very grateful!

In my designer file:

```
<div id="pdfShow" runat="server"> </div>
```

In my .cs file:

```
string str = dt.Rows[0]["pdfPage"].ToString();
byte[] dataPdf = Convert.FromBase64String(str);
pdfShow.InnerHtml = "data:application/pdf;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(dataPdf);
```

When I put a breakpoint, I can see the value from my database passed to pdfShow, but nothing is displayed.

Comment: @k-j yes I have got a very long string, which I think it is the problem. Thank you.

Comment: how about transmit the bytes as PDF file to user? and let the user decides how he/she wants to open it